# How can I tell which bridges I have already flown under & can fly under for the Under the Bridge Challenge?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

The question says it all, is there a way to tell which bridges I have already flown under?

Is there a list or map of all of the bridges that apply to this challenge?  I have flown under a few bridges that I knew I haven't flown under (due to me still exploring the map), and the challenge did not trigger.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know of a way to tell which bridges you have or haven't flown under, but I do know that not all bridges qualify for the challenge.

Comment: You have to mark it down yourself.

Comment: if it helps, the in-game website: junkenergydrink.com shows all the bridges you have to fly under, as well as stunt/base jumps

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Currently, there's no easy way like the spaceship parts and letter fragments tracked on rockstar social club. But you can always go medieval and use a physical solution.

I found the fold-out map included with in the game box to be pretty useful for this. And once I've finished (almost there!) it'll make a cool (geeky) piece of art to hang in the media room.

The pins are map tacks found at a local store for under $6 total. If you're curious, green is bridges, yellow is jumps, white is letters, and blue is spaceship parts. I've yet to do any knife flights.

[image: Map of San Andreas with map tacks]

As for which bridges to fly under, there's no way to know without using a guide. I'm sure it's not hard to find one out there. But if you don't want to use a guide, you just have to keep trying bridges. I do have a couple tips though: Use a helicopter, it's much easier. Also, make sure you don't scrape the walls or top of the bridge with your rotors. Sometimes that causes it not to trigger. There are two bridges in particular where this is very difficult, so use a small helicopter like the Military one you can buy from the in-game internet.

Answer (score 8):

I realise I'm a little late to the party, but...

I created an online map for just this purpose: http://gta-5-map.com

Just go there, sign in, click 'My Progress' and then start ticking of the markers on the map.

Hope it helps!

Comment: You did this? Great work!

Comment: this is fantastic, good job!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry you're out of luck. There's currently no way to track this like the other collectibles that are visible on the social club map.

There's also some bridges that are not included in the challenge for some reason. There are multiple videos on Youtube showing what bridges qualify. Just search for "under the bridge gta 5".